# How to use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for a timestamptz field in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

## tl;dr

`NEW.updated_at := NOW();` is not working, where `updated_at` stores a `timestamptz` value.

I have this trigger function, where the error seems to happen in the first line. The `updated_at` field stores a `timestamptz` value, which `NOW()` should be, but doesn't seem to work (throws error). I have tried both `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `NOW()` and neither seems to work. Does anyone know what might be causing this issue?

```sql
BEGIN
  NEW.updated_at := NOW();
  UPDATE public.projects 
  SET updated_at = NEW.updated_at 
  WHERE id = NEW.project_id;
  INSERT INTO public.document_contributor (document_id, contributor)
  VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.created_by)
  ON CONFLICT
  DO NOTHING;
  INSERT INTO public.commits (message, created_by, project_id, document_id, created_at, previous_content, current_content)
  VALUES (NEW.note, NEW.updated_by, NEW.project_id, NEW.id, NEW.updated_at, OLD.content, NEW.content);
  RETURN NEW;
END
```

### Error

#### Event message

```
invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "Invalid Date"
```

I've noticed that the query being made looks like this.

```json
{
  "query" : "\n-- source: dashboard\n-- user: 201e7b7c-bb29-409f-9e01-65ca849999e6\n-- date: 2022-10-09T01:44:28.100Z\n\nupdate public.documents set (created_at,updated_at,note,data) = (select created_at,updated_at,note,data from json_populate_record(null::public.documents, '{\"created_at\":\"Invalid Date\",\"updated_at\":\"Invalid Date\",\"note\":null,\"data\":[{\"type\":\"title\",\"children\":[{\"text\":\"Untitled\"}]},{\"type\":\"paragraph\",\"children\":[{\"text\":\"Pool 입니다.\"}]}]}')) where id = 'c5e2348b-9da7-4db3-8d5e-9d669cfbd7cb' returning *;\n"
}
```

Comment: "*doesn't seem to cooperate with me*" - what's the problem? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, it is causing an error. I have edited the post.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Could the error be happening somewhere else? Which pg version are you using?

Comment: @JohanMaes The current version is version PostgreSQL 14.1 on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 10.3.0, 64-bit

Comment: Perhaps you can't use `NEW.updated_at` as a variable for the UPDATE / INSERT statements? Have you tried using `now()` directly?

Comment: demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/4cFS4TJE `NEW.updated_at := NOW();` is not the problem.

Comment: @Johntopia Look at the logs of the postgres server. It should have more details about where exactly the error occurred, and does usually even contain the value that failed to be converted.

Comment: What table is the trigger on? What client is throwing the error message?

Comment: @Johntopia Please [post error messages as text, not a painting of them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1048572)!

Comment: @AdrianKlaver The function is a trigger for the `documents` table. When a document record is updated, a trigger function is fired. Also, I do not understand the meaning of client in this context sorry. (I am still fairly new to RDBs.)

Comment: @jian No, it doesn't seem to be the direct cause. However, the problem is that `NOW()` doesn't return a valid `timestamptz` type value.

Comment: @JohanMaes What do you mean by using `now()` directly?

Comment: @JohnanMaes I don't think using the variable itself is the problem. You can see here(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) in the documentation, where a similar example is given for the case of a `INSERT` or `UPDATE` trigger function.

Comment: `now()` is a `timestamptz` and can be cast to one: `select pg_typeof(now()); timestamp with time zone` and `select now()::timestamptz; 10/08/2022 21:20:23.23468 PDT`. That is not the issue. The issue is here `...{\"created_at\":\"Invalid Date\",\"updated_at\":\"Invalid Date\"` from `json_populate_record()`.  The values  `"Invalid Date"` date are by no means  valid `timestamptz`'s.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Hmm, I have been testing this on the Supabase GUI. Perhaps, the issue could originate from the Supabase client?

Comment: The problem is in whatever is creating the JSON object to begin with. It is using values(`Invalid Date`) that are not correct timestamp values.

Comment: Indeed, you'll have to check how that initial query (`update public.documents...`) is generated and where that text `Invalid Date` comes from.

Answer (score -1):

```
BEGIN
  NEW.updated_at = NOW();
  UPDATE public.projects 
  SET updated_at = NEW.updated_at 
  WHERE id = NEW.project_id;
  INSERT INTO public.document_contributor (document_id, contributor)
  VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.created_by)
  ON CONFLICT
  DO NOTHING;
  INSERT INTO public.commits (message, created_by, project_id, document_id, created_at, previous_content, current_content)
  VALUES (NEW.note, NEW.updated_by, NEW.project_id, NEW.id, NEW.updated_at, OLD.content, NEW.content);
  RETURN NEW;
END
```

Comment: What did you change and why? I can't even spot the difference.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Turns out the "time" of the trigger function was the issue.

In the official document, the operation happens `BEFORE`.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER emp_stamp BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON emp
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION emp_stamp();
```

But I have done the opposite, which was `AFTER` an update happens.

SO when I recreated the function changing from `AFTER` to `BEFORE`, it works fine.

The reason? Well I am guessing that updating the record by `RETURN NEW`, AFTER the operation finishes violates some rule. (But I am not sure)

Comment: Not seeing how? In an `after` trigger `return new` is ignored. Which means `new.updated_at` would not be used in the `documents` table. That would lead to a different error then the one you see, which is based on the value `Invalid Date` that comes from the JSON in the original update.